# Cannot display special characters / unicode correctly

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8

When I tried to print special characters like this:

```
String tmp = "笑 ¥123";
byte[] array = tmp.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s = new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(tmp);
System.out.println(s);
```

Both my Mac console and IntelliJ IDEA displays correctly:

```
笑 ¥123
笑 ¥123
```

But AWS console displays:

```
? ?123
? ?123
```

What is missing here?

If I use:

```
new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8").println(tmp);
```

the output is correct. I don't really understand this. Can someone explain? Thank you.

Comment: You do realize that converting `tmp` to a UTF-8 byte array and then creating a new `String` from that array using UTF-8 for decoding will produce the original `String` value, don't you? You may as well get rid of `array` and `s` and pass `tmp` around as needed.

Comment: Yes. I am using the original "tmp" now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the AWS console supports (or most likely, is configured to display) the UTF-8 encoded characters you're correctly sending.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. I just noticed a warning on AWS console, right after login in: -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory. Not sure if this is related. I followed instruction on http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/os-x-terminal-bash-warning-setlocale-lc_ctype-cannot-change-locale/ to remove the warning and install required locale. Running "sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8" on AWS seems to solve the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Running "sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8" on AWS solves the problem.